# Basic issues with BlueJ and Java running program

Tags: java, bluej

I want to run a program, as of right now the class only has a singular call to place an image of a cathedral on the canvas. However, at the bottom of the code there is a command to create and run the program (CHApplet). This is supposed to make the whole thing execute nicely, but instead it's giving me a confusing white screen with nothing on it

Here's the code:

```
import cha.*;
import cha.action.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.awt.Color.*;

/**
 * Setting
 *
 * Arch Morrison
 * v1
 */
public class Cathedral
extends CHApplet
{
    public void init() {

      CHImage cathedral;
      cathedral = new CHImage();
      add(cathedral);
      cathedral.setFile("cathedral.jpg");
      cathedral.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);

    }

    public static void run() {
        CHApplet applet;
        applet = new CHApplet();
        int width = 600;
        int height = 600;
        CHApplet apply = new Cathedral();
        applet.run(width, height);
    }

     private Cathedral() {
        }
}
```

I should mention that there isn't an error message, the code compiles and runs but doesn't display a canvas as BlueJ normally does.

[image: Image of the empty Applet]

Comment: Java is not Javascript, they are two totally different things.

Comment: thanks my guy, i just updated the tag and title

Comment: Your `run` method calls `run` on the `CHApplet`, I think you wanted to call that on `apply` instead (which is the actual `Cathedral` instance).

Comment: Hey, that did it!! Thanks so much man.

Comment: @BigOlCoderBoy The thing is that you picked the wrong one. You are programming in Java, not Javascript. I've changed it back to "Java". Pease make sure you understand the difference between the two.